# iOS UIWebView: How can I figure out what the previous URL is?

Tags: ios, url, uiwebview, browser-history

I'm rewriting the goBack function with my own because I need to be able to change the URL depending on whether the orientation changed or not. How can I access the URL history and figure out the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the UIWebViewDelegate. It has methods that will allow you to control the back functionality as well as letting you capture the URL when you navigate to it.

Comment: Hmm I see that it doesn't have a history object or anything like that. Is making an array of some sort as my own history object my best shot here?

Comment: Yes, unless you just want to tell the web view to go back, at which point it will do so without needing a URL.